# I need help finding $f(x,y)$

Tags: partial-differential-equations

1. $\frac{\partial}{\partial y}f(x,y)=\frac{\partial ^2}{\partial x^2}f(x,y)$, and
2. $f(x,0)=e^x$

It seems like $f(x,y)=e^{x+y}$ but I can't prove it.

Comment: Look into "separation of variables" (Assume $f(x,y)=a(x)*b(y)$). Also you are missing some conditions. What is $f(0,y), f(L_x,y), f(x,L_y)$? If $x$ and $y$ can be infinity then also assume that f is bounded at infinity.

Comment: Is the function modeling a specific physical value? You may be able to intuit more conditions from the physics.

Comment: I was listening to quantum mechanics lecture online and there was no additional condition. I searched on wikipedia, and I could not find additional condition there too. This is basically schrodinger's equation without coefficients. 2 is assuming energy eigenstate and the professor and wikipedia page derived directly that $f(x,y)=e^{x+y}$.

Comment: [This](https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/physics/8-04-quantum-physics-i-spring-2013/lecture-notes/MIT8_04S13_Lec06.pdf) is the lecture note. It should be on the first page. And [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schrödinger_equation#Nonrelativistic_quantum_mechanics) is the wikipedia page.

Comment: Isn't it a heat equation? as $y$ stands for time variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "easy" way to prove a solution satisfies is to just plug it into the equation
$$ \frac{\partial}{\partial y}(e^{x+y}) = e^{x+y} $$
$$ \frac{\partial^2}{\partial x^2}(e^{x+y}) = e^{x+y} $$

If you want to actually solve it, one method is to use separation of variables. Suppose

$$ f(x,y) = X(x)Y(y) $$

Then from the equation we get
$$ X''Y = XY' $$

or
$$ \frac{X''}{X} = \frac{Y'}{Y} = \lambda $$

where $\lambda$ is some arbitrary constant. (the only way for a function of $x$ to equal a function of $y$ is of they're both constant)

From this you have 3 cases

- If $\lambda = 0$ then $X'' = Y' = 0$, thus the general solution is 
  $$f(x,y) = Ax+B$$
- If $\lambda > 0$ then $\lambda = k^2$ and the solution is 
  $$ f(x,y) = (Ae^{kx} + Be^{-kx})e^{k^2y} $$
- If $\lambda < 0$ then $\lambda = -k^2$ and the solution is
  $$ f(x,y) = (A\cos kx + B\sin kx)e^{-k^2y} $$

We can easily that only the second case gives an exponential in $x$, so that must be the solution form. Then
$$ f(x,0) = Ae^{kx} + Be^{-kx} $$

matching coefficients gives $k=1$, $B = 0$, $A = 1$. Therefore
$$ f(x,y) = e^xe^y = e^{x+y} $$

Comment: You used the "separation of variable". I'm not familiar with that concept but my understanding after reading the wikipedia page tells me that it is an assumption to derive one solution of the differential equation. Shouldn't you also prove that it does not have a solution if $f(x,y)$ does not satisfies the assumption?

Comment: How well do you know PDEs? Separation of variables is a very common method for linear equations. I'm also not really sure what you're asking. What do you mean by "$f(x,y)$ does not satisfy the assumption"? What assumption? The initial condition?

Comment: This method gives the most general form of the solution. Since this equation is also very general, not much more needs to be done. However, if you had additional boundary conditions, or different function forms, the solution can be presented in the form of an infinite series (a consequence of the law of superposition)

Comment: I have no experience on PDEs. There are bivariate functions that does not satisfy $f(x,y)=X(x)Y(y)$ such as $\sin(x+y)$. That was what I meant by not satisfying the assumption. I now get it why it is enough to assume it. Thanks.